# Message failed to send on android app using telephony

Tags: java, android, telephony, smsmanager

I have this function that I am using to send message to recipent on shake

ShakeDetector.create(this, () -> {

```
        //if you want to play siren sound you can do it here
        //just create music player and play here
        //before playing sound please set volume to max

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String ENUM = sharedPreferences.getString("ENUM","NONE");
        if(!ENUM.equalsIgnoreCase("NONE")){
            manager.sendTextMessage(ENUM,null,"Im in Trouble!\nSending My Location :\n"+myLocation,null,null);

        }

    });
```

Message is opened in recipents chat and it shows "failed to send" in my message app
when I try to resend that same message manually It works fine

I tried using multiple devices and multiple recipents. Please anybody help me resolve this issue